# Configuring nanoc so it will output files in the same directory without renaming them?

Tags: ruby, configuration, nanoc

When I ***"compile"*** with `nanoc` everything ends up in the output directory, but each page ends up in its own directory, (with the exception of the root `index.html` file).  Is there any way to configure `nanoc` so that it outputs all the files to the same directory renaming them to their original file names?

I haven't found anything in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a routing rule like the following:

```
route '*' do
  item.identifier.chop + '.' + item[:extension]
end
```

If your goal is to have an area under `content/` that gets copied verbatim to the output, a better approach would be to set up a static data source that will read these files without dropping their extension and also allow you to keep them in a folder separate from the other, non-static items. The nanoc troubleshooting page has [instructions on setting this up](http://nanoc.ws/docs/troubleshooting/#error-found-3-content-files-for-x-expected-0-or-1) ("Solution #2").

Comment: I suspect the instructions have been removed in the current version of that troubleshooting page...?

Comment: @kevinrutherford They have, and in fact [the static data source has itself been removed](http://nanoc.ws/doc/nanoc-4-upgrade-guide/#upgrading-from-the-static-data-source) from Nanoc 4, which apparently now preserves file extensions and so doesn't really demonstrate the issue this question is addressing. Are you able to upgrade to Nanoc 4?